# "Edit Summary" How to edit a post correctly?

Tags: discussion, editing

After editing a post, I always put the original text (word, command line etc.) that I removed into the **Edit Summary**. For example, if I removed "plz help me" or "i need help plzz", that's what I put in the edit summary.

Is that the right way to do it?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? Perhaps add an example? Do you mean that you put the phrases you removed into the edit summary? And what exactly are you asking about?

Comment: @terdon Exactly , i past the removed phrases (wrong phrase) to the "edit summary"

Comment: OK, and you are asking if that is a good idea? Is that what you mean by "the best way to edit"? Or are you asking something more general about editing? Is your question only "what should I put in the edit summary"?

Comment: By the way, I just made a substantial edit to your question to make it clearer. Please check that I didn't change what you wanted to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The edit summary should explain to the author of the post and to anyone else who reads it why the edit was made. So, instead of writing "plz help me" there, write something like "Removed irrelevant text" or "There's no reason to write things like 'pls help me'" or some other informative message.

The idea is that the user whose post you edited will be able to read the message and understand why the you chose to edit.

Comment: +1, and just to put a finer point on it, the edited (added & removed) text is visible on the edit history -- no need to repeat the changed text -- so the 'why' really is more valuable long-term.